# How to read from a csv file to create a scala Map object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a path to a csv I'd like to read from. This csv includes three columns: "topic, key, value" I am using spark to read this file as a csv file. The file looks like the following(lookupFile.csv):

```
Topic,Key,Value
fruit,aaa,apple
fruit,bbb,orange
animal,ccc,cat
animal,ddd,dog

//I'm reading the file as follows
val lookup = SparkSession.read.option("delimeter", ",").option("header", "true").csv(lookupFile)
```

I'd like to take what I just read and return a map that has the following properties:

- The map uses the topic as a key
- The value of this map is a map of the "Key" and "Value" columns

My hope is that I would get a map that looks like the following:

```
val result = Map("fruit" -> Map("aaa" -> "apple", "bbb" -> "orange"),
                 "animal" -> Map("ccc" -> "cat", "ddd" -> "dog"))
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read in your data

```
val df1= spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load(path)
```

first put "key,value" into and array and groupBy Topic to get your target 
separted into a key part and a value part.

```
val df2= df.groupBy("Topic").agg(collect_list(array($"Key",$"Value")).as("arr"))
```

now convert to dataset

```
val ds= df2.as[(String,Seq[Seq[String]])]
```

apply logic on the fields to get your map of maps and collect

```
val ds1 =ds.map(x=> (x._1,x._2.map(y=> (y(0),y(1))).toMap)).collect
```

now you data is set up with the Topic as a key and "key,value" as a Value, so now apply Map to get your result

```
ds1.toMap

Map(animal -> Map(ccc -> cat, ddd -> dog), fruit -> Map(aaa -> apple, bbb -> orange))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val in = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv("""Topic,Key,Value
     | fruit,aaa,apple
     | fruit,bbb,orange
     | animal,ccc,cat
     | animal,ddd,dog""".split("\n").toSeq.toDS)
in: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Topic: string, Key: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val res = in.groupBy('Topic).agg(map_from_entries(collect_list(struct('Key, 'Value))).as("subMap"))
res: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Topic: string, subMap: map<string,string>]

scala> val scalaMap = res.collect.map{
     | case org.apache.spark.sql.Row(k : String, v : Map[String, String]) => (k, v) 
     | }.toMap
<console>:26: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] (the underlying of Map[String,String]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
       case org.apache.spark.sql.Row(k : String, v : Map[String, String]) => (k, v)
                                                     ^
scalaMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Map[String,String]] = Map(animal -> Map(ccc -> cat, ddd -> dog), fruit -> Map(aaa -> apple, bbb -> orange))
```